# A Question related to the Formula Hierarchy

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Let large Latin symbols as $X$ and $Y$ denote sets of natural numbers and small symbols as $n$ and $n´$ denote natural numbers and small Greek letters stand for formulas.

Suppose $\alpha$ is $\Pi_1^0$ or $\Sigma_1^0$. Is ($\forall X$)($\exists n$)($\forall Y$)$\alpha(X,Y,n)$ $\Pi_2^1$, or what?

Comment: Where? It’s $\Pi^1_1$ if you have $\Sigma^1_1$-AC, but only $\Pi^1_3$ otherwise.

Comment: @Emil I do not understand the import of the question for location.

Comment: “Where” = “in which theory do you need the formula to be proven equivalent to something of a particular complexity”. Regarding the second comment, I’d rather leave that to someone familiar with subsystems of second-order arithmetic, however, I assume so by analogy with the corresponding question in the arithmetic hierarchy: no true $\Pi_2$-axiomatized theory can prove that all $\forall\exists\forall\Delta_0$ formulas with the existential quantifier bounded are equivalent to $\Pi_2$ formulas (whereas $B\Sigma_1$ proves they are $\Pi_1$).

Comment: It is in the context of a modal ontological argument I have developed, with roots in the work of Gödel and others - including myself. (Details on request.)  The complexity issue will only figure as an incidental remark, and the matters are of course further complexified by the presupposition of a second order $modal$ machinery. 


I guess my association mentioned below to Skolem is to the point?

Comment: For the record and to make issues comprehensible, I deleted a question which Emil related to and which asked whether his "only" could be replaced by something like "even".

Comment: Let me put it more clearly: these formulas are certainly $\Pi^1_3$ with almost no assumptions on the base theory, as one can simulate number quantifiers by set quantifiers. They are probably not in general $\Pi^1_2$ (or even $\Pi^1_1$) unless the base theory is sufficiently strong, but this requires proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18271/discussion-between-frode-bjordal-and-emil-jerabek).

Comment: I should say that I was ignoring the requirement on the complexity of $\alpha$; the speculation that the formula may not be $\Pi^1_2$ without $\Sigma^1_1$-AC was supposed to apply to arbitrary arithmetic $\alpha$ (though $\Sigma^0_2$ should suffice). As shown in François’s answer, this makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Indeed, for *strict* $\Sigma^1_1$-formulas of the form $\exists X\phi(X,n)$ where $\phi(X,n)$ is $\Pi^0_1$, choice follows from $\mathsf{WKL}_0$. Additionally, if $\phi(X,n)$ is $\Sigma^0_2$ then choice follows from $\mathsf{ACA}_0$. The general case is when $\phi(X,n)$ is $\Pi^0_2$ (the complexity of saying that a set is the graph of a total function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an additional twist in the case where $\alpha$ is $\Sigma^0_1$. Assuming $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ ([Weak König Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig's_lemma)), $\forall Y\alpha(X,Y,n)$ is equivalent to a $\Sigma^0_1$ statement and hence so are $\exists n \forall Y \alpha(X,Y,n)$ and $\forall X\exists n \forall Y\alpha(X,Y,n)$.

The reason why $\exists X\phi(X)$ remains $\Sigma^0_1$ can be seen as follows. The verification that $\phi(X)$ holds for a specific $X$ can only use a finite amount of information about the set $X$. It follows that if we identify subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with their characteristic functions, then $\{X \subseteq \mathbb{N} : \phi(X)\}$ is an open set in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. Because $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact, $\forall X\phi(X)$ holds if and only if there is an $n$ such that $\phi(X)$ holds for every $X \subseteq \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ and $\phi(X)$ only uses information about membership in $X$ for numbers less than $n$ (and therefore $\phi(X')$ also holds whenever $X = X' \cap \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$). Since subsets of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ are easily coded using numbers $\{0,\ldots,2^n-1\}$ this means that $\forall X \phi(X)$ is equivalent to a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula $\exists n\forall x < 2^n\widehat{\phi}(n,x)$, where $\widehat{\phi}(n,x)$ can be effectively computed from the original formula $\phi(X)$.

Note that this doesn't work if one uses functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ instead of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ since Baire space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is far from compact.

---

As Emil pointed out in the comments, a similar trick applies for the case when $\alpha(X,Y,n)$ is $\Pi^0_1$. Suppose $\alpha(X,Y,n)$ is $\forall m\alpha_0(X,Y,n,m)$ where $\alpha_0(X,Y,n,m)$ is bounded. Because universal quantifiers commute, $\forall Y\alpha(X,Y,n)$ is equivalent to $\forall m\forall Y\alpha_0(X,Y,n,m)$. Because $\alpha_0(X,Y,n,m)$ is bounded, the statement $\exists Y\lnot \alpha_0(X,Y,n,m)$ is equivalent to a $\Sigma^0_1$ statement for if $\alpha_0(X,Y,n,m)$ holds for some set $Y$ it also holds for some finite set $Y$. (Furthermore, this is provable in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ instead of $\mathsf{WKL}_0$.) It follows that the negation $\forall Y\alpha_0(X,Y,n,m)$ is equivalent to a $\Pi^0_1$ statement and hence $\exists n\forall Y\alpha(X,Y,n)$ is equivalent to a $\Sigma^0_2$ statement. Finally, we conclude that $\forall X\exists n\forall Y\alpha(X,Y,n)$ is $\Pi^1_1$ and this is provable in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$.

The Kleene Normal Form Theorem (provable in $\mathsf{ACA}_0$) shows that every $\Sigma^1_1$ statement is equivalent to one of the form $\exists X\phi(X)$ where $\phi(X)$ is $\Pi^0_2$ (since $\Pi^0_2$ is enough to characterize graphs of total functions). So the last statement $\forall X\exists n\forall Y\alpha(X,Y,n)$ could be as complex as any other $\Pi^1_1$ statement assuming $\mathsf{ACA}_0$. Therefore, this case does not lead to a perpetual collapse as in the previous case.

Comment: This is a very good point. Do I understand it correctly that if $\alpha$ is $\Pi^0_1$, a similar agument makes the formula $\Pi^1_1$ already in RCA_0?

Comment: @François Somehow your statement must be further and appropriately qualified it seems to me. If not, the whole second order formula hierarchy of Second Order Arithmetic collapses for systems stronger than $WKL_0$, right?

Comment: (Of course, there is a qualification in that the argument presupposes the compactness of $2^\mathbb{N}$.)

Answer (score 7):

It's $\Pi^1_1$ - you can shuffle number quantifiers around set quantifiers, and "fuse" two second-order quantifiers of the same type (just as you can with first-order quantifiers).

Essentially the proof of quantifier shuffling: consider the sentence $\psi\equiv\exists n\forall X\varphi(n, X)$ where $\varphi$ is some formula. This is equivalent to the following statement: $$\hat{\psi}\equiv\forall X\exists i\varphi(i, X_i)$$ where $X_i$ denotes the $i$th row of $X$, thinking of $X$ as an array of sets via some nicely definable bijection $\omega\cong\omega^2$. The point is: if $\psi$ is true, then clearly $\hat{\psi}$ is true. Meanwhile, if $\psi$ is false, then we can pick a sequence of sets $X_i$ such that $\neg\varphi(i, X_i)$; then $X=(X_i)_{i\in\omega}$ provides a counterexample to $\hat{\psi}$.

If memory serves, this is treated in more detail in Kleene's original paper on the arithmetic and analytic hierarchies, "???." There he also treats the problem of simplifying the matrix of a sentence in the analytic hierarchy: if $\varphi$ is an arithmetic formula, and $Q$ is some block of second-order quantifiers, then $$Q\varphi\equiv Q\hat{\varphi}$$ for some $\Sigma^0_1$ formula $\hat{\varphi}$.

---

EDIT: In my argument showing that it's $\Pi^1_1$, I'm invoking "enough logic;" in particular, I need to be able to build the sequence $(X_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of counterexamples, just by knowing that a counterexample exists for each $i$. As Emil points out in his comment, this is (at least from the point of view of reverse math) a very strong assumption: in particular, a weak theory - say, $RCA_0$ - may not be able to prove that your sentence is $\Pi^1_1$ (more precisely, there may be no $\Pi^1_1$ sentence which $RCA_0$ proves is equivalent to your sentence). So it depends what you are asking for: provable complexity over some theory, or "true" complexity.

Comment: I am also interested in the foundational issues here, and even true complexity.

As a follow up, this reminds me of Skolem functions. Is my association to the point?